# Perl search and replace using variables, string contains dot

Tags: regex, perl

I’m using a variable to search and replace a string using Perl.
I want to replace the string `23.0` with `23.0.1`, so I tried this:

```
  my $old="23.0";
  my $new="23.0.1";
  $_ =~ s/$old/$new/g;
```

The problem is that it also replaced the string `2310`, so I tried:

```
  my $old="23\.0"
```

and also `/ee`.
But can’t get the correct syntax for it to work. Can someone show me the correct syntax?

Answer (score 4):

There are two things that will help you here:

The `quotemeta` function - that will escape meta characters. And also the `\Q` and `\E` regex flags, that stop regex interpolation.

```
print quotemeta "21.0";
```

Or:

```
my $old="23.0";
my $new="23.0.1";
my $str = "2310";
$str =~ s/\Q$old\E/$new/g;
print $str;
```

Comment: \Q and \E are not regex features, they work anywhere you do double-quotish interpolation

Answer (score 1):

Just use single quotes and escape the dot.

```
my $old='23\.0';
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement Sobrique's excellent answer, let me note that the reason your attempt with `"23\.0"` didn't work is that `"23\.0"` and `"23.0"` evaluate to the same string: in a double-quoted string literal, the backslash escape sequence `\.` simply evaluates to `.`.

There are several things you could do to avoid this:

- If you indeed want to match a fixed string, and don't need or want to include any special regexp metacharacters in it, you can do as Sobrique suggest and use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) or `\Q` to escape them.

  In particular, this is almost always the correct solution if the string to be matched comes from user input.  If you *do* want to allow some limited set of non-literal metacharacters, you can unescape those *after* running the pattern through `quotemeta`.  For a simple example, here's a quick-and-dirty way to turn a basic [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)-like pattern (using the metacharacters `?` and `*` for "any character" and "any string of characters" repectively) into an equivalent regexp:

  ```
  my $regexp = "^\Q$glob\E\$";  # quote and anchor the pattern
  $regexp =~ s/\\\?/./g;        # replace "?" (escaped to "\?" by \Q) with "."
  $regexp =~ s/\\\*/.*/g;       # replace "*" (escaped to "\*" by \Q) with ".*"
  ```
- Conversely, if you want to have a literal regexp pattern in your code, without immediately matching it against something, you can use the [`qr//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qr.html) regexp-like quote operator, like this:

  ```
  my $old = qr/\b23\.0(\.0)?\b/;  # match 23.0 or 23.0.0 (but not 123.012!)
  my $new = "23.0.1";             # just a literal string

  s/$old/$new/g;          # replace any string matching $old in $_ with $new
  ```

  Note that `qr//` has other effects beyond just allowing you to use regexp syntax in a string literal: it actually pre-compiles the pattern into a special Regexp object, so that it doesn't need to be recompiled every time it's used later.  In particular, as a side effect, the string representation of a `qr//` regexp literal will usually not exactly match the original content, although it will be equivalent as a regexp.  For example, `say qr/\b23\.0(\.0)?\b/` will, on my Perl version, output `(?^u:\b23\.0(\.0)?\b)`.
- You could also just use a normal double-quoted string literal, and double any backslashes in it, but that's (usually) less efficient than using `qr//`, and also less readable due to [leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

  Using a single-quoted string literal would be slightly better, since backslashes in a single-quoted string are only special when followed by another backslash or a single quote.  Even so, readability can still suffer if you happen to need to match any literal backslashes in your regexp, not to mention that it's easy to create subtle bugs if you forget to double a backslash in those rare places where it's still needed.